# Maya expression syntax error

Tags: expression, maya, mel

What is wrong with the following expressions that I am trying to set on a particular attribute in Maya. All are just different approaches.

**Expression 1:**

```
directionalLightShape1.intensity = sqrt(noise(time));
```

**Error:**

```
expression -s "directionalLightShape1.intensity = sqrt(noise(time));"  -o directionalLightShape1 -ae 1 -uc all ;
// Error: line 0: Invalid argument(s) for sqrt. // 
// Error: line 0: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. // 
// Result: expression1 // 
// Error: line 0: Invalid argument(s) for sqrt. // 
// Error: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. //
```

**Expression 2:**

```
float $n = noise(time);
directionalLightShape1.intensity = sqrt($n);
```

**Error:**

```
expression -e -s "float $n = noise(time);\ndirectionalLightShape1.intensity = sqrt($n);"  -o directionalLightShape1 -ae 1 -uc all  expression1;
// Error: line 1: Invalid argument(s) for sqrt. // 
// Error: line 0: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. // 
// Result: expression1 // 
// Error: line 1: Invalid argument(s) for sqrt. // 
// Error: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. //
```

**Expression 3:**

```
float $n = sqrt(`noise time`);
directionalLightShape1.intensity = $n;
```

**Error:**

```
expression -e -s "float $n = sqrt(`noise time`);\ndirectionalLightShape1.intensity = $n;"  -o directionalLightShape1 -ae 1 -uc all  expression1;
// Error: line 0: Invalid call to "noise".  Check number and types of arguments expected by the procedure. // 
// Error: line 0: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. // 
// Result: expression1 // 
// Error: line 0: Invalid call to "noise".  Check number and types of arguments expected by the procedure. // 
// Error: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. //
```

**Expression 4:**

```
float $n = noise(time);
directionalLightShape1.intensity = `sqrt $n`;
```

**Error:**

```
expression -e -s "float $n = noise(time);\ndirectionalLightShape1.intensity = `sqrt $n`;"  -o directionalLightShape1 -ae 1 -uc all  expression1;
// Error: line 1: Invalid argument(s) for sqrt. // 
// Error: line 0: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. // 
// Result: expression1 // 
// Error: line 1: Invalid argument(s) for sqrt. // 
// Error: An execution error occured in the expression expression1. //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `(noise(time) + 1)/2` if you see artifacts from using `abs`.

Depending on the application the truncation of the range might be an issue.

Comment: shouldn't it be `/2`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with all the stated expressions is that `noise` was returning *negative* value. Which when fed to `sqrt` was naturally supposed to throw an error which wasn't quite evident at first.

Replacing `noise(time)` with `abs(noise(time))` solved the problem.